# Dual boot (2 linux os)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Здравствуйте, возможно ли установить 2 линукс системы на компьютер (убунту и хром ОС? Как быть с грабом/бут разделом?
Не совсем понимаю принцип, кто может объяснить?

Comment: поставьте эту *dalvik/linux* и посмотрите, что к чему. а потом уже приходите за решением **конкретных** проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Самый простой вариант: установить ChromeOS, при установке разбить диск на 3 раздела, 2 для каждой ОС и раздел подкачки (swap), загрузчик установить на жесткий диск, а не на раздел, а саму систему на один из разделов. Потом, установить Ubuntu на другой раздел, раздел подкачки можно использовать на обе системы, загрузчик установить на сам жесткий диск. Загрузчик сам увидит, что на другом разделе есть ChromeOS и добавит её в список выбора системы для загрузки. А потом можно и настройки Grub под свои нужды скорректировать, при необходимости, документации в сети хватает.